# How to solve this Boundary Value Problem? (Using Fourier)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform, boundary-value-problem

$u_{tt} = u_{xx} - u$
Boundary condition: $u(x,0)=f(x), u_t(x,0)=0,$ $f(x)$ is a Schwartz function.

I tried to make $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$, then I get  $\frac{X}{X''}=\frac{T}{T'' + T}$.
Let  $\frac{X}{X''}=\lambda$, then $X''=\lambda X $ and $T'' + (1-\lambda )T=0$.
Then I stuck on that. What should I do next?

Comment: Do the Fourier transform, get $\hat u_{tt}=-\xi^2\hat u-\hat u$, solve the ODE to get $\hat u(\xi, t)=\hat f(\xi)\cos\sqrt{1+\xi^2}t$, then do the inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: @Yuval I understood the first equation, but how to use boundary condition to get the second equation?

Comment: For any fixed $\xi$, the equation $(\hat u)''_{tt}=-(1+\xi^2)\hat u$ is a 2nd order linear ODE that one can solve with the initial condition $\hat u(0)=\hat f$ and  $(\hat u)'(0)=0$.